# Кеширование изображений

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Кешируются ли изображения в браузере , если оно подключено как background-image(css)? 
Если кэшируются то на какое время ?

Answer (score 3):

При чтении `css` браузер ничего предварительно не загружает. Изображения кешируются когда они отображаются на сайте уже. А кешируются ли, и на сколько - это зависит от настроек хедеров на сайте.

Т.е. в этом плане изображения загруженные через `<img src="">` и `css-бэкграунды` не отличаются.

Answer (score 1):

Все браузеры кеширую изображения до принудительного обновления страницы, например если заходить на страницу в **opere**, она при повторных посещениях берет изображения и js из кеша, а вот если взять и нажать F5 или ОБНОВИТЬ страницу, то она снова перечитывает и перезагружает все файлы.
Это сделанно для снижения нагрузки на сайты.
Время это задается настройками браузера, не подскажу где именно, не копался, врать не буду.
Но в опере есть, например, опция - брать изображения принудительно из кеша, для экономии трафика, но я думаю щас это не актуально, имхо современный интернет довольно быстрый, раньше да, было актуально, когда я сидел с GPRS